# i want to add latitude and longitude to this javascript but the map is not showing after adding the options

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to add lat and longtitude to my javascript which can be maually enter by user but it is not showing  the map and if i remove the javascript  to add lat and long it works fine.

```js
 function initMap()


        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            zoom: 10,
            center: test,
            map: map
        }); 
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: test,
            map: map
        });
    }
```

```css
                     #map {
                         width: 50%;
                         height: 400px;
                         background-color: grey;
                     }
```

```html
<html>
  <title>Google Maps on webPage</title>
  <body>
     <input type="number"  id="txtlat" name="txtlat" placeholder="Latitude">
     <input type="number" id="txtlng" name="txtlng" placeholder="Longitude">
     <button onclick="fncheck()">Click</button>  
     <div id="map"></div>

      <script async defer src ="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCdldYO5Ho4VxIFD9jjvT6meNDGROs4w4c&callback=initMap">
      </script>
    <script>
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(x, y)
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the function `fncheck()`?

Comment: most likely this code should be wrapped in this function `fncheck()` - `var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng (x, y)`

Comment: I don't know whats fncheck() took the code from somewhere from here .it said add this script to add  latitude and longitude button.I am new to java script.if there is any other way to add lat and long to enter manually you all can suuggest pls.

Comment: sergey its not working